# User-specified print settings in GTK applications are silently overriden by system printer defaults

Tags: gnome, firefox, printing, libreoffice, evolution

**UPDATE:**
***I have since ascertained that this appears to be a GTK printing issue, after testing in multiple desktop environments (GNOME, Cinnamon, MATE, XFCE, and KDE Plasma) and trying to print in different applications.  The problem is present in all DEs when printing from GTK applications, but KDE/Qt applications are UNAFFECTED.  With this added information, does anybody have an idea about how to resolve this issue?***

I have been testing Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on multiple computers on our network and have been having issues printing to network printers using user-specified settings.  When I print from an application like Firefox (either snap or apt version), LibreWriter, or Evolution, the print dialogs allow me to select options like duplex (double-sided) printing and color-vs-monochrome printing. The actual, physical print process, however, does not respect the options I select in the application print dialog(s) and instead prints according to the system-wide duplex and color options set in the GNOME-control-center Printer settings.

I've tried changing the duplex and color options in the application print dialogs in multiple ways, for example, using the default Firefox print dialog and also the "Print using the system dialog..." option, both of which fail to have any effect on the final printout, which simply follows the System-wide duplex and color settings.  I've also tried changing the default values via the CUPS web interface, but it also has no effect (the resultant printouts print according to the system-wide gnome-control-center settings for the selected printer and ignore the settings selected by the user and CUPS defaults without any indication to the user about what is happening).

Printers:

- Lexmark XM3150, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.15  (monochrome
  printer, so only the duplex issue is obviously occurring)
- Xerox AltaLink C8170, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.15 (color
  printer- both duplex and color-mode application print settings are
  overridden by the settings in the Gnome Control Center, without any
  indication to the user that this is happening)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Ubuntu/GNOME Settings→Printers
2. Click printer's Gear_button→Printing Options→Page Setup→Select "One Sided" for the Two-sided option.
3. Click printer's Gear_button→Printing Options→Color→Select "Color" for the Print Color Mode.
4. Print a document from LibreWriter, Firefox, or Evolution using the
   application's print dialog, selecting the options for "duplex" and
   "Monochrome" printing.
5. The printout(s) do not print double-sided or monochrome, as specified
   by the user in the application print dialogs, and the user is not
   warned that his/her settings are not being accepted or used. The
   printouts instead print according to what has been selected in the
   Ubuntu/Gnome Settings→Printers, which the user may have no idea
   about, leading to much frustration, confusion, repeated tries, and
   wasted paper.

Thank you in advance for any help, pointers, or advice.

Answer (score 0):

The printing problem has been resolved with the following workaround (I consider this a workaround, since such arcane steps should not be required to attain the expected behavior that users expect by default):

In the CUPS web administration, modify the target printer (there are multiple discovered entries for each network printer) as follows:

-Select a version of the printer in which the connection does not begin with "implicitclass://"
-Use the official PPD from the printer manufacturer when asked to select a Make/Model from the list (simply supplying the official PPD and doing nothing else does not work— for the Lexmark, it worked in half of the testing, for the Xerox, nothing would print at all)

Here are the current settings that are now working:

Description:    Lexmark_XM3150
Driver: Lexmark XM3100 Series (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection:     dnssd://Lexmark%20XM3150._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=46ddad31-ac9a-4001-827e-a73bc92ff831

Description:    Xerox_AltaLink_C8170_9F_31_43
Driver: Xerox AltaLink C8170 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection:     ipps://Xerox%20AltaLink%20C8170%20(9F%3A31%3A43)._ipps._tcp.local/

User-specified settings during printing now work as expected in all applications.